# neo4j.rb check relation already exists between two nodes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, graph-databases, neo4j.rb

I Need to check relation between two nodes exists already.

```
brian.following << chris
brian.following
#=> chris
```

I Need to check like this

```
brian.following?(chris)
#=> true
brian.following?(john)
#=> false
```

1. Any method is there in neo4j.rb for this?
2. if not, How can i write my custom method for this in Neo4j.rb-Rails ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do `brian.following.include?(chris)`. Check out https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/wiki/Optimized-Methods, it details this and many other helpful methods that are either modified versions of those found in Enumerable and unique to QueryProxy. You'll also find examples of these in https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/master/spec/e2e/query_proxy_methods_spec.rb.